# I want to set rules for new users to get signup verification by Admin in Firebase authentication for android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner for android developing, i had designed APP.

I want to use Firebase Email and Password Auth for my APP.

But for user registration, when user registers then the approval needs to be given by admin for User to login.

So I dont know how to set rules for this.

Please help on this.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that before:

When the user complete the registration, you will have the following attributes in the Auth tab:

User Id: 585878

User Email: mh@stackoverflow.com

You can save this user inside the firebase database with attributes like :

User Id / User Email / Approved (boolean)

And now the firebase Auth will only verify against the Auth things if its fine you can make a request into the firebase database to verify if its approved or no.

you can read more about Identity Verification: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/